# What should be the value that i can pass other than X for an CHECKBOXTYPE in XML

Tags: xsd

Hi all i am an XML Schema where i have the following

```
<xsd:element name="Check" type="CheckboxType">
 <xsd:annotation>
     <xsd:documentation>
       <Description>Check</Description>
        <LineNumber>12</LineNumber>
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
   </xsd:element>
```

While assigning the value or inner text for this field it is taking only `X`. What's the other value that i can pass other than `X`. I think `X` is assigned when i checked a check box, but what's the other value that i can assign to that `Node` when check box was not checked

Comment: You would have to show us the definition of `CheckboxType`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to specify an absence of a value. Below two are two generic ways.

**Option 1**

Do not add the element in the XML instance. If this is the right option or not is dependent upon the context and hard to tell without knowing more information

**Option 2**

Use `xsi:nil="true"` attribute in the XML instance. You can read more about the [usage on zvon.org](http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_over_st0.html). To use this change your element definition as below

```
<xsd:element name="Check" type="CheckboxType" nillable="true">
 <xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:documentation>
     <Description>Check</Description>
     <LineNumber>12</LineNumber>
   </xsd:documentation>
 </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

You can then have the XML instance as below

```
<Check xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```